# Use of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, tuples

I have the following question: Create a function called `column_cutoff` that takes, as input, a pandas dataframe and a list of tuples. The tuples should have the following format: `(column_name, min_value, max_value)`. The function should return a dataframe which excludes rows where the value in a specified column exceeds max_value or is less than min_value.

I should not remove rows if the column value is equal to the min/max value
As follows

```
def column_cutoff(data_frame, cutoffs):
    return
```

Could you please help me?
Hi I have tried the following:

```
def column_cutoff(data_frame, cutoffs):
    data_subset = data_frame
for column_limits in cutoffs:
     data_subset = data_subset.loc[data_subset[column_limits[0]] >= column_limits[1],:]
     data_subset = data_subset.loc[data_subset[column_limits[0]] <= column_limits[2],:]
return data_subset
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Hello. I have added what I have tried!

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to my question has as follows:

def column_cutoff(data_frame, cutoffs):
for column_limits in cutoffs:
data_subset = data_frame.loc[data_frame[column_limits[0]] >= column_limits[1],:]
data_subset = data_frame.loc[data_frame[column_limits[0]] <= column_limits[2],:]
return data_subset

Many thanks