# How to write a function that returns a dataframe which excludes rows where the value in a specified column exceeds max_value or is less than min_value

Tags: python

I have been trying to solve this question but it seems I am not selecting the column limits correctly even though the code runs with no errors. What am I doing wrong?  (I have included a screenshot of the feedback from the autograder because it would not let me copy and paste)

Create a function called column_cutoff that takes, as input, a pandas dataframe and a list of tuples. The tuples should have the following format:(column_name, min_value, max_value). Your function should return a dataframe which excludes rows where the value in a specified column exceeds max_value or is less than min_value.

NOTE: DO NOT remove rows if the column value is equal to the min/max value

```
def column_cutoff(data_frame, cutoffs): 
    for column_limits in cutoffs: 
        
        is_within_limit_1 = (data_frame[column_limits[0]]) >= (column_limits[1])
        new_df1 =  data_frame[is_within_limit_1] 
        is_within_limit_2 = (new_df1[column_limits[0]]) <= (column_limits[2])
        new_df2 =  new_df1[is_within_limit_2]          
        
    return new_df2
```

I know it runs wrong because when I submit the code to the autograder, I get this feedback [image]

I have also tried this but it also appears to be wrong. I get the same error like that in the screenshot.

```
def column_cutoff(data_frame, cutoffs): 
    for column_limits in cutoffs:  
        
        new_df = data_frame[(data_frame[column_limits[0]] >= column_limits[1]) & (data_frame[column_limits[0]] <= column_limits[2])]
        
    return new_df
```

Comment: You're creating `new_df1` and `new_df2` twice - once for each element in `cutoffs`. You're then returning only the last `new_df2`.

Comment: Ultimately, I need to return only 1 data frame. So new_df2 is a subset of new_df1. How should I go about combining both new_df1 and new_df2 while ensuring the returned data frame is within the limits?

Comment: You can refer this question for solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65955931/returning-greater-than-and-less-than-values-in-pandas

Comment: check here for answer   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62781695/use-of-dataframes